# Why the following code returns "none" in print statement?

Tags: python

I run the following code:

```
class mobile:
    def __init__(self, name, brand):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
class cpu(mobile):
    def get_name(self):
        print("This mobile has HighTech %s CPU " % self.name)    
brand = cpu("Intel","Sony")
print(brand.get_name())
```

The result is:

```
This mobile has HighTech Intel CPU
None
```

Why does it return 'None' in second line?

Comment: You're calling the `get_name` method of `cpu` class that is polymorph and does not return anything, so by default, it returns `None`. Just do not print `brand.get_name()` or make `return "This mobile has HighTech %s CPU " % self.name`.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` statement when calling the `get_name` function is redunant, try:

```py
class mobile:
    def __init__(self, name, brand):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
class cpu(mobile):
    def get_name(self):
        print("This mobile has HighTech %s CPU " % self.name)    
brand = cpu("Intel","Sony")
brand.get_name()
```

Inside `get_name()` you already state a `print` statement, therefore no second `print` outside the function is necessary.